# Cannot convert Class to Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class, codedom

I'm trying to make a Windows Form Application, that can compile another Windows Form Application. But I'm getting a couple of errors, set in the CodeEntryPointMethod (CodeDom), when i'm setting up the default Main method to run the Winform.

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)' has
>   some invalid arguments
>
> Argument '1' cannot convert from
>   'kjpUnityGameLauncherTemplate.Launcher' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

The CodeEntryPointMethod looks like this:

```
CodeEntryPointMethod start = new CodeEntryPointMethod();

CodeMethodInvokeExpression mainClassSetup = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Application)), "Run",
    new CodeObjectCreateExpression(typeof(kjpUnityGameLauncherTemplate.Launcher)));
start.Statements.Add(mainClassSetup);
```

My 'Launcher' class/Form:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace kjpUnityGameLauncherTemplate
{
    public partial class Launcher : Form
    {
        public Launcher()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Launcher_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "It works!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I'm seeing you should cas you class to a `Form` explicitly;

Comment: But how do I do that?

Comment: If Tico's right, you should just be be able to prepend (Form) like so: `(typeof((Form)kjpUnityGameLauncherTemplate.Launcher))` I believe.

Comment: That won't work, because I get an error saying "System.Windows.Forms.Form" is a type, but is used like a variable.